# gdal_translate with aux.xml as input

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gdal-translate

I'm trying to translate a tif file to EPSG3857 system. I have an .aux.xml file that contains GCP pairs generated from ArcGIS after georeferencing.

I know that gdal_translate could take GCP pairs as input parameters following
`[-gcp pixel line easting northing [elevation]]`. But I wonder if could take GCP pairs from .aux.xml directly?

The .aux.xml file looks like this:

```
<PAMDataset>
  <Metadata domain="Esri">
    <MDI key="PyramidResamplingType">NEAREST</MDI>
  </Metadata>
  <Metadata domain="xml:ESRI" format="xml">
    <GeodataXform xsi:type="typens:PolynomialXform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:typens="http://www.esri.com/schemas/ArcGIS/2.6.0">
      <PolynomialOrder>1</PolynomialOrder>
      <SpatialReference xsi:type="typens:ProjectedCoordinateSystem">
        <WKT>PROJCS["WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",0.0],PARAMETER["Auxiliary_Sphere_Type",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0],AUTHORITY["EPSG",3857]]</WKT>
        <XOrigin>-20037700</XOrigin>
        <YOrigin>-30241100</YOrigin>
        <XYScale>148923141.92838538</XYScale>
        <ZOrigin>-100000</ZOrigin>
        <ZScale>10000</ZScale>
        <MOrigin>-100000</MOrigin>
        <MScale>10000</MScale>
        <XYTolerance>0.001</XYTolerance>
        <ZTolerance>0.001</ZTolerance>
        <MTolerance>0.001</MTolerance>
        <HighPrecision>true</HighPrecision>
        <WKID>102100</WKID>
        <LatestWKID>3857</LatestWKID>
      </SpatialReference>
      <SourceGCPs xsi:type="typens:ArrayOfDouble">
        <Double>3.3670799903498199</Double>
        <Double>14.344873843184562</Double>
        <Double>4.0247295778244734</Double>
        <Double>6.6759905605576932</Double>
        <Double>20.679283661800582</Double>
        <Double>18.262229934276547</Double>
        <Double>13.211044941102045</Double>
        <Double>16.778168540971819</Double>
        <Double>12.244455330248002</Double>
        <Double>24.086990859475918</Double>
        <Double>2.1280975663810295</Double>
        <Double>25.129290588782169</Double>
        <Double>12.933283313915354</Double>
        <Double>7.2568573062017094</Double>
        <Double>20.454005901884102</Double>
        <Double>1.7238579583936371</Double>
        <Double>13.491290735737039</Double>
        <Double>1.6423177213873714</Double>
        <Double>4.8163223174578889</Double>
        <Double>0.72613202838692814</Double>
      </SourceGCPs>
      <TargetGCPs xsi:type="typens:ArrayOfDouble">
        <Double>-12353281.166067505</Double>
        <Double>3792598.784185593</Double>
        <Double>-12353265.702508822</Double>
        <Double>3792473.8355942797</Double>
        <Double>-12352975.120627346</Double>
        <Double>3792673.6957177576</Double>
        <Double>-12353101.981132057</Double>
        <Double>3792639.885362898</Double>
        <Double>-12353119.545305107</Double>
        <Double>3792796.2039722297</Double>
        <Double>-12353304.614491669</Double>
        <Double>3792789.8768205559</Double>
        <Double>-12353104.676498685</Double>
        <Double>3792482.6936066402</Double>
        <Double>-12352969.275452796</Double>
        <Double>3792380.5101070567</Double>
        <Double>-12353094.236698417</Double>
        <Double>3792374.1829553796</Double>
        <Double>-12353247.986484168</Double>
        <Double>3792353.9360700133</Double>
      </TargetGCPs>
      <Name />
    </GeodataXform>
  </Metadata>
</PAMDataset>
```